# angularjs ng-repeat evaluated with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a way to do an ng-repeat with an expression. Here is what I currently have.

```
<tr ng-cloak id="{{$index}}"
          ng-repeat-start="item in currentContoller.items | 
          orderBy: '-time'">
    <td>item.a</td>
    <td>item.b</td>
</tr>
```

what I am looking for is something like this, where firstItemOnly is a checkbox

```
<tr ng-cloak id="{{$index}}"
          ng-repeat-start="item in currentContoller.items | 
          orderBy: '-time' | 
          if ({{firstItemOnly}}) {limitTo: 1}"> //this is the line that needs added
    <td>item.a</td>
    <td>item.b</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post what firstItemOnly is. Can you explain what `if firstItemOnly` is checking?

Comment: you can do the whole expression in ternary operator inside angular expression like `item in (firstItemOnly ? (item in currentController.items | orderBy: '-time') : (something else))`

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving a problem like this is to think outside of the box. Instead of trying to use an expression *within* the `ng-repeat`, add an expression to the collection itself:

```
// create a function that returns the relevant collection of items
$scope.getItems = function() {
    // if first item only, return the first item
    if (this.firstItemOnly)
    {
        return this.items.slice(0, 1);
    }

    // otherwise, return all items
    return this.items;
};

...

<tr ng-cloak id="{{$index}}"
    ng-repeat-start="item in getItems() | orderBy: '-time'">
```

Answer (score 0):

tried using $first ?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

use ng-if with $first and show a checkbox. bob=auntie :)